# Retrieve data from HC_05 in Android through Bluetooth

Tags: android, eclipse, bluetooth, arduino

I am trying to develop one Android that will retrieve data from Arduino Board through Hc-05 Bluetooth model. I faced the problem to read the data from the hardware. I can able to connect with the hardware but I cannot retrieve the data that are coming in every second from the hardware. I did the following...

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connection in progress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        myLabel.setText("Connection in Progress");
        try 
        {
             findBT();
             openBT();

        }
        catch (IOException ex) { }


    }




    void findBT() 
    {


        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if(mBluetoothAdapter == null)
        {
            myLabel.setText("No bluetooth adapter available");
        }

        if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
            Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 1);
        }

        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if(pairedDevices.size() > 0)
        {
            for(BluetoothDevice device1 : pairedDevices)
            {
                if(device1.getName().equals("HC-05")) 
                {
                    mDevice = device1;
                    myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Device Found");
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(pairedDevices.size()==0){myLabel.setText("Please Pair devices");}
        }




    }
```

Comment: What exactly did you do? Please attach the error logs as well!

Comment: thank you @ Thiagoir,now I cannot understand how to retrieve data from the hardware

Comment: What does your `openBT()` look like?

Comment: I am trying to make one method named "openBT() " using this data will be retrieved... but I could not write the code....please help me